# Lua incremental parser library?

Tags: parsing, lua

Lua language incremental parser library? (in Lua itself or other language)

Comment: The hell is an incremental parser?

Comment: @DeadMG: Maybe, "An incremental parser is a device which is able to perform syntax analysis in an incremental way, avoiding complete reparsing of a program after each modification." From abstract at http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=357066

Comment: We're gonna need a verb somewhere in there if you're looking for a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try LPEG. Here - http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html#grammar